# Returning they key with lowest value in a nested hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this hashmap:

`{count : {req : deadline}, count : {req : deadline}, count : {req : deadline}, count : {req : deadline}}`

If I put it in values is:
`{0 : {req : 5}, 1 : {req : 3}, 2 : {req : 1}, 3 : {req : 3}}`

I want to compare all the `deadline` values and see which one has the lowest value and return the `count` that has that `deadline`.

So in this case the lowest "deadline" = 1, which corresponds to the "count" = 2.

Comment: Maybe hashmap isn't the data structure you really need? Something tells me you want a priority queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HashMap` of type `<Integer, DataHolder>` and then sort the map based on values and access the first element.

> See below code

```
public class Sample {

    static class Data {
        String key;
        Integer value;

        public Data(String key, Integer value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data{" +
                    "key='" + key + '\'' +
                    ", value=" + value +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Map<Integer, Data> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(0, new Data("req", 5));
        map.put(1, new Data("req", 3));
        map.put(2, new Data("req", 1));
        map.put(3, new Data("req", 3));

        List<Map.Entry<Integer, Data>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getValue().value));
        System.out.println(list.stream().findFirst().get().getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!
Just one more thing, if i wanna know just acess the key "req" from the dataholder, how do i do it? Can i use "hashmap.get(count).key?"

Comment: I want to acess the string "req", how do i do it?
I tried "String process = req.get(count).key;" but it gives me java.lang.NullPointerException on the thread.

Comment: @Godogo If you want to retrieve ```req```, you can do ```hashMap.get(key).key```